# pushbutton to change variable

Tags: matlab, button, push

I guess this is a very simple question, but I am spending more time searching for the answer, than I would if I'd ask here

I made 3 pushbuttons, when I click on of them, a variable has to be changed, so like:

```
[Button1] when pressed: bp = sys
[Button2] when pressed: bp = mean
[Button3] when pressed: bp = dia
```

This is what I have so far, I copied the code from a button that resumes a script. What do I need to adjust to fit my need?

```
kiessys = uicontrol( 'Position', [10 35 60 30],'String','Sys(R)','Callback','uiresume( gcbf )' );
kiesmean = uicontrol( 'Position', [10 70 60 30],'String','Mean(B)','Callback','uiresume( gcbf )' );
kiesdia = uicontrol( 'Position', [10 105 60 30],'String','Dia(G)','Callback','uiresume( gcbf )' );
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there you go:

```
global bp;

figure
kiessys = uicontrol( 'Position', [10 35 60 30],'String','Sys(R)','Callback', {@fun, 'sys'});
kiesmean = uicontrol( 'Position', [10 70 60 30],'String','Mean(B)','Callback', {@fun, 'mean'});
kiesdia = uicontrol( 'Position', [10 105 60 30],'String','Dia(G)','Callback', {@fun, 'dia'});
kiesdia = uicontrol( 'Position', [10 140 200 30],'String','Output current value','Callback', 'disp(bp)');
```

and store the callback-function `fun` to `fun.m`:

```
function fun(~, ~, value)
    global bp;
    bp = value;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Alexandrew's answer is good, however you can do it without using the "fun" function. Just type in the "callback" string the commands, i.e.

```
kiessys = uicontrol( 'Position', [10 35 60 30],'String','Sys(R)','Callback', 'bp = sys;');
kiesmean = uicontrol( 'Position', [10 70 60 30],'String','Mean(B)','Callback','bp = mean;');
kiesdia = uicontrol( 'Position', [10 105 60 30],'String','Dia(G)','Callback', 'bp = dia;');
```

The commands will run in the "base" workspace and the variables will be visible to any script. This way you don't have to declare them as *global*, which is generally not a good practice.

A note on creating GUIs in Matlab. It is a good practice (best actually) to use GUIDE to create the gui than using commands, as it simplifies things considerably and is a lot faster in development (just consider that you have to create 10 buttons, 2 axes etc using commands... positioning them alone is a nightmare).

Comment: Good hint. Yeah I already wanted to post something about the `global` thing, which also could have been solved by using attributes of a handle-class, which surely would have been of a overhead in this case surely, but if the function is going to be extended, it might be helpful